# Not able to authenticate in GitLab through username and password using python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, gitlab, python-gitlab

I am using the following python code provided as an alternative to the now defunct usage of the username and password in the python-gitlab library which acts as a wrapper over the GitLab REST API to login into GitLab:

```
import re
import sys

import requests

import gitlab


URL = 'https://gitlab.com'
SIGN_IN_URL = 'https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in'
LOGIN_URL = 'https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in'

session = requests.Session()
sign_in_page = session.get(SIGN_IN_URL).content
# Next line in the code causes the error described below!
for l in sign_in_page.split('\n'):
    m = re.search('name="authenticity_token" value="([^"]+)"', l)
    if m:
        break

token = None
if m:
    token = m.group(1)

if not token:
    print('Unable to find the authenticity token')
    sys.exit(1)

data = {'user[login]': 'login_or_email',
        'user[password]': 'SECRET',
        'authenticity_token': token}
r = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=data)
if r.status_code != 200:
    print('Failed to log in')
    sys.exit(1)

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(URL, api_version=4, session=session)
```

I am receiving the following error code in line 16:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/saurav/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/gitlab_auth_code.py", line 16, in <module>
    for l in sign_in_page.split('\n'):
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

There seems to be some issue with the usage of the `'\n'` character for the next line. How do I mend this error? This code is actually provided in the official python-gitlab documentation as a workaround using python requests and I believe it should work: https://gist.github.com/gpocentek/bd4c3fbf8a6ce226ebddc4aad6b46c0a

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: How about `sign_in_page.split(b"\n")` ?

Comment: I tried that, but then I received this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/saurav/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/gitlab_auth_code.py", line 17, in <module>
    m = re.search('name="authenticity_token" value="([^"]+)"', l)
  File "C:\Users\saurav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\re.py", line 199, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: Your `sign_in_page`  is byte. You can change it to string: `str(session.get(SIGN_IN_URL).content)`. Afterwards, this issue will be eliminated.

Comment: There's another issue though, based on the same question, @wanderlust if you'd want to check that out, here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721758/is-it-possible-to-login-to-gitlab-using-python-gitlab-using-username-email-and-p